# MATLAB: Rehash Seemingly Only Works with a Full Second of Delay

Tags: git, matlab

I am working on a tool in MATLAB that checks out various Git commits of a numerical library, successively runs benchmarks on each, and then compares them. The purpose is to check for performance degradation over time. So, given commits `c1` and `c2` and benchmarks `b1` and `b2`, the sequence of operations would be

1. check out `c1`
2. run benchmarks `b1` and `b2`
3. check out `c2`
4. run benchmarks `b1` and `b2`
5. restore the previous state of the repo.

Now I found a problem: I made a commit where the main numerical function throws an exception as soon as it's called. Now, if `c1` is the commit that throws and `c2` is tested after `c1`, the benchmarking run with `c2` will also crash with the same exception, indicating that MATLAB is still using the code from `c1`.

I tested this by making some dummy commits, where the function that throws the exception (or not) also prints out which version it is in each commit. Then I also rigged my commit loader module to print the function's code, loaded directly from the file, and its `stat` including update timestamp. I found that the function's code and `stat` are always up to date, but the print statement inside the function is out of date *iff* the code (i.e. whether or not it throws an exception) is out of date. This shows that `git checkout` indeed updates all files properly before terminating, and it is MATLAB that is failing to recognize the file changes.

I noticed that long delays - sometimes even the version that instantly throws an exception takes long, maybe due to CPU scheduling or garbage collection, I don't know - increase the likelihood of MATLAB detecting the changes. In particular, I had some cases where the timestamps of old and new versions were something like `14:05:31:889` and `14:05:32:101` (notice how it's only 200ms, but it rolled over a second) and MATLAB did load the new code correctly.

So, sounds like a case for [rehash](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rehash.html), right? Well, I added it to the commit loader module, right after `git checkout`, and it does nothing.
In fact, I even used `rehash path`. As far as I know, that unconditionally updates files on the path without checking if their timestamps have changed. The thing I just mentioned where the crashing commit taking a long time, or there happening to be a second between commits makes MATLAB recognize the update again, happens all the same.

I hope I managed to explain the situation well enough, please tell me if it's confusing.

So now the question is:
can I set `rehash` to be more sensitive, to check on a millisecond basis? Did I misunderstand `rehash path`? Or is this a known bug? Because it seems like neither `rehash` nor `rehash path` make any difference. I'm using MATLAB r2023a on Ubuntu 2022.04.4 LTS.

Here is the code where I tried to use `rehash`:

```matlab
            [status, cmdout] = SystemUtil.safeSystem(sprintf("git checkout %s", sha));
            if status ~= 0
                throw(this.genericGitError(cmdout));
            end
            rehash path;
            disp(datetime(datetime(), "Format", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS"));
            [status, cmdout] = system("stat mainFunction.m");
            disp(cmdout);
            text = fileread("mainFunction.m", "Encoding", "utf-8");
            lines = split(text, newline);
            disp("actual file contents: " + lines(2)); % line 2 is where it says which version it is
```

Comment: You might want to look at the [docs for `clear`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html), perhaps you need to use `clear classes` , `clear functions`,  or `clear all`, which all clear functions from memory. Check out the useful table half way down the docs page.